# React.Context refers to a UMD global

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I created the following context.tsx:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

export interface LibsAndComponentsInterface {
  data: unknown[];
}

export const LibsAndComponentsContext = createContext<
  LibsAndComponentsInterface | undefined
>(undefined);
```

And use it in my Wrapper component:

```
import { ReactNode, useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { LibsAndComponentsContext } from 'core/context/dataContext';
import { useApiService } from 'common/hooks/useApiService';
import { useAuth } from 'common/contexts/Authentication';

// Wrap your App component with this
export function LibsAndComponentsProvider({
  children,
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
}) {
  const [libs, setLibs] = useState<unknown[]>([]);
  const [components, setComponents] = useState<unknown[]>([]);

  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
  const { sendRequest } = useApiService();

  useEffect(() => {
    .....
  }, []);

  const ctxValue = useMemo(
    () => ({
      data: [...libs, ...components],
    }),
    [libs, components],
  );

  return (
    <LibsAndComponentsContext.Provider value={ctxValue}>
      {children}
    </LibsAndComponentsContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useLibsAndComponents() {
  const ctx = useContext(LibsAndComponentsContext);

  if (ctx == null) {
    throw new Error(
      'useLibsAndComponents must be inside LibsAndComponentsProvider',
    );
  }

  return ctx;
}
```

I get now an error returned for `<LibsAndComponentsContext.Provider value={ctxValue}>`

> 'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
> 'React' must be in scope when using JSX

I do not see where I am referencing as a module, could somebody point me to the error?

Comment: What's your TSConfig? Have you considered doing what the error suggests? `import React from "react";`

Comment: I feel so embarrassed and dumb right now, this was really the problem... thanks for spotting my mistake!

Answer (score -1):

Adding `import React from "react";` was the embarrassing solution.